# EncodeDecodeAES encrypt and decrypt issue in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have written code for encrypt and decrypt the data. When I run the Android demo did not issue for encryption but my data is decrypt and occur the exception like:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '+' as integer

Here is my EncodeDecodeAES class.

```
public class EncodeDecodeAES {
    private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    private final static int JELLY_BEAN_4_2 = 17;

    private final static byte[] key = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0 };



    public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());

        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());

        String fromHex = toHex(result);

        String base64 = new String(Base64.encodeToString(fromHex.getBytes(), 0));

        return base64;

    }

    public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] seedByte = seed.getBytes();

        System.arraycopy(seedByte, 0, key, 0,
                ((seedByte.length < 16) ? seedByte.length : 16));

        String base64 = new String(Base64.decode(encrypted, 0));

        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seedByte);

        byte[] enc = toByte(base64);

        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);

        return new String(result);

    }

    public static byte[] encryptBytes(String seed, byte[] cleartext)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());

        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext);

        return result;

    }

    public static byte[] decryptBytes(String seed, byte[] encrypted)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());

        byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, encrypted);

        return result;

    }

    private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {

        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); // , "SC");

        SecureRandom sr = null;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= JELLY_BEAN_4_2) {

            sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");

        } else {
            sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

        }

        sr.setSeed(seed);

        try {

            kgen.init(256, sr);

            // kgen.init(128, sr);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // Log.w(LOG,
            // "This device doesn't suppor 256bits, trying 192bits.");

            try {

                kgen.init(192, sr);

            } catch (Exception e1) {

                // Log.w(LOG,
                // "This device doesn't suppor 192bits, trying 128bits.");

                kgen.init(128, sr);

            }

        }

        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();

        byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();

        return raw;

    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); // /ECB/PKCS7Padding", "SC");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);

        return encrypted;

    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted)
            throws Exception {

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); // /ECB/PKCS7Padding", "SC");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

        return decrypted;

    }

    public static String toHex(String txt) {

        return toHex(txt.getBytes());

    }

    public static String fromHex(String hex) {

        return new String(toByte(hex));

    }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {

        int len = hexString.length() / 2;

        byte[] result = new byte[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)

            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2),
                    16).byteValue();

        return result;

    }

    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {

        if (buf == null)

            return "";

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {

            appendHex(result, buf[i]);

        }

        return result.toString();

    }

 private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {

        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));

    }

}
```

And here is my Activity Code which is i want to send the data on server and get return back response from the server with decrypt my data and show on the log cat which is decrypt or not.

```
 String encrypted="Dyv6ACIDe2q+OEjztjfNDw==";

 @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json)

            {
                super.onPostExecute(json);

                try
                   {

                        json.put(KEY_REQUEST_ID, RequestId);
                        json.put(KEY_REQUEST_CODE, RequestCode);
                          json.put(KEY_CHANNEL_ID, stringChannelId);
                        json.put(KEY_IP_ADDRESS, str_Device_IP_Address);
                       json.put(KEY_USERNAME, strUserName);
                       json.put(KEY_PASSWORD, strPassWord);

                                    String jstr = json.toString();

                                    Log.e("in","onPostExecute(String json) = " + jstr);

                                    String encrypted1 = EncodeDecodeAES.encrypt(json.toString(), textToEncrypt);
                                    System.out.println("encrypted1  =" + encrypted1);

                                    JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();
                                    jSONObject.put(KEY_REQUEST, encrypted1);
                                    jSONObject.put(KEY_VENDOR_ID, "1");
                                    String jsonString = jSONObject.toString();


                                    JSONObject jSONObject_outer = new JSONObject();
                                    jSONObject_outer.put("W2INBCWS", jSONObject);
                                    String strJobject2=jSONObject_outer.toString();

                                   // JSONObject data = new JSONObject(strJobject2);
                                    String decrypted = EncodeDecodeAES.decrypt(strJobject2, encrypted);
                                    System.out.println("decrypted  =" + decrypted);

                             } 

                             catch (JSONException e)

                             {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                             } 

                             catch (Exception e) 
                             {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                           pDialog.dismiss();

                         }
```

Here is my Log Cat stack trace .

```
12-06 16:33:44.893: W/System.err(1024): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '+' as integer
12-06 16:33:44.893: W/System.err(1024):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:528)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at com.window2india.EncodeDecodeAES.toByte(EncodeDecodeAES.java:183)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at com.window2india.EncodeDecodeAES.decrypt(EncodeDecodeAES.java:53)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at com.window2india.Login$GetJSONParse.onPostExecute(Login.java:195)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at com.window2india.Login$GetJSONParse.onPostExecute(Login.java:1)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-06 16:33:44.903: W/System.err(1024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-06 16:33:44.914: W/System.err(1024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 16:33:44.914: W/System.err(1024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-06 16:33:44.914: W/System.err(1024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-06 16:33:44.914: W/System.err(1024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-06 16:33:44.914: W/System.err(1024):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 16:33:49.183: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1024): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: can you provide us the full stack trace?????

Comment: @Sathish , Thanks for the replay . Wait a minute i will post.

Comment: it seem the issue is coming from the  `result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2),
                    16).byteValue();` You need to check whether the string you are parsing is an integer

Comment: @Sathish , I don't understand what are you saying .

Comment: pls check that in the code block which i have mentioned in the previous comment.. you are parsing string into integer right?? if so pls check that statement you are parsing an integer... i hope so in that code block only u r getting the issue

Comment: @Sathish , No I'm not parse the any String into Integer.Becouz my all values are in String format

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42644/discussion-between-tazeenmulani-and-sathish)